# Speed controller, service or subscriber/publisher?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I am making a PI speed controller for a robot, should I use a service or a subscriber for my Python script?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329540/speed-controller,-service-or-subscriber/publisher?/) by [bhejase](https://answers.ros.org/users/36156/bhejase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you should use a  "subscriber/publisher"topic, because you like to controll you mobile robot with a twist message.  und the output of you controller is not importent for the publisher node.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0